# Cannot get thumbnails for images on nautilus but can for video

Tags: nautilus, thumbnails, previews

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and ever since I installed it afresh, I have not been able to get thumbnail of normal files, like .png, .jpg, etc. However, unlike other posts, I can actually get thumbnails of videos and such.

Where should I look and how would I diagnose the issue?[Example of thumbnail issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIqpz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I had tried the usual of stopping nautilus from previewing, removing the thumbnails directory, etc. I even tried writing my own custom thumbnail creator using ImageMagick. Whatever the reason, neither worked. In the end, I was able to figure out that I needed `gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer`, and installed it and repeating the process of deleting directories, `killall nautilus`, and opening Nautilus again, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Found this question when experiencing the same problem myself. The package in the other answer, `gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer` did not exist for me when I tried to find it. But searching for that quickly found `libgtk-pixbuf2.0-bin`, which did solve the problem after installation and restarting Nautilus.

Just to describe the problem a bit more for the search algorithms:
Existing thumbnails were still displaying, I suspect the change came when I upgraded to 18.04, but I didn't notice at the time. Wiping the thumbnail directories, `~/.cache/thumbails` and `~/thumbnails` only succeeded in deleting my existing thumbnails, causing no thumbnails to be shown for anything. It did not fix the issue as it has for many other people with similar thumbnail generation issues.

Examination of the `~/.cache/thumbnails/fail` directory seemed to indicate that nautilus wasn't even trying to generate thumbnails. Installation of thumbnailers for videos, specifically `ffmpegthumbnailer`, did work and did create thumbnails. As well as some failures in the fail directory. Unfortunately, it seems that most of the documentation regarding GNOME thumbnailers is outdated at best, and rarely covers the built-in thumbnailers. As well, the results of tools such as `gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders` seemed to indicate that I already had the proper libraries installed to generate thumbnails for png, jpg, and other 'default' files.

While other `pixbuf` libraries were already installed, namely: `gtk2-engines-pixbuf`, `libgtk-pixbuf2.0`, `libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common`, `libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev`, and `gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0`, the needed one, `libgtk-pixbuf2.0-bin`, was not. This had earlier fooled me into thinking that pixbuf was already correctly installed.

Hopefully this helps other people find the correct problem and thus the correct answer faster than I did.